# Algorithm for matching point sets

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

I have two sets of points `A` and `B`, whereas the points can be 2D or 3D. Both sets have the same size `n`, which is rather low (5 - 20).

I would like to know how well these sets agree. That is, ideally I would find pairings between the points such that the sum of all Euclidean pair distances `d(A,B)` is minimal. So

`d(A,B) = \sum_{i=1}^n ||A_i - B_i||_2`

The final outcome is used to compare with other point sets. So, for example:

- A = (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)
- B = (1,1), (2,2), (1,3)

would give me `d(A,B) = 1`.

- C = (1,1), (2,1), (3,1)
- D = (2,1), (2,2), (3,1)

would give me `d(C,D) = 1.414`.

Any good ideas?

Comment: How do you achieve `d(C,D) = 2` ? What inter-point distance do you use ? Check http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P6.html

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I would use euclidean distance.

Comment: The formula that you are using to calculate `d(a,b)` is not at all obvious.  Please clarify.

Comment: Your link lead me to this paper containing a compact description of the algorithm: Sayan Bhattacharya. A Survey on Algorithms for Euclidean Matching. http://db.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps234/fall08/projects/sayan_proj.pdf

Comment: Hidden behind the scenes here is a graph problem (bipartite matching with minimum cost) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example model your problem as an **assignment problem** ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)), where you define the cost C_ij of assigning point A_i (from set A) to point B_j (from set B) to be equal to the distance between them. This assignment problem can then be solved using the Hungarian algorithm ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)).

Comment: Your answer is already very helpful. The algorithm is O(n^3). It would be great if there is a faster algorithm for my case.

Comment: I realized that the Earth Mover's Distance, which I had mentioned in my question, also utilizes the Hungarian algorithm. However, it is using optimizations (e.g. the fact that costs stem from a metric). So it seems to be the best choice for me.