# Looking for algorithm to match up objects from 2 lists depending of distance

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, distance

So I have 2 lists of objects, with a position for each one. I would like to match every object from the first list with an object of the second list.
Once the object of the second list is selected for a match up, we remove it from the list (thus it can not be matched with another one). And most importantly, the total sum of distances between the matched up objects should be the least possible.

### For example:

*list1* **{ A, B, C }** *list2* **{ X, Y, Z }**

So if I match up A->X (dist: 3meters) B->Z (dist: 2meters) C->Y (dist: 4meters)
Total sum = 3 + 2 + 4 = 9meters

We could have another match up with A->Y (4meters) B->X (1meter) C->Z (3meters)
Total sum = 4 + 1 + 3 = 8meters <======= **Better solution**

Thank you for your help.

Extra: Lists could have different length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm for matching point sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050678/algorithm-for-matching-point-sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) (a [weighted matching in bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))).

An algorithm which solves this is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). At the bottom of the wikipedia article is also a list of implementations.

If your data has special properties, like your two sets are 2D points and the weight of an edge is the euclidean distance, then there are [better algorithms](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/P6.html) for this.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I can use such solution for my problem aswell.